# I want to Know what Physics Pang Game use in Ball Bounce

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to make ball control like pang game. I write this code but sill missing something or i am doing something wrong.

I try to use Physical Material but i cant control it.
When i set bounce to 1 Y position will increase with every frame. So i cant so anything with that.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Collied");

    if(other.tag == "rightWall")
    {
        direction = false;
    } 
    else if(other.tag == "leftWall")
    {
        direction = true;
    }

    if(other.tag == "groundWall") rigid.velocity = Vector3.up * 10;
    if(other.tag != "topWall")  BallMove(); 
}

void BallMove()
{
    if (direction == false)
    {
        rigid.AddForce(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(-300f, 0, 0), Time.deltaTime * ballForce));
    }
    else
    {
        rigid.AddForce(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(300f, 0,0), Time.deltaTime * ballForce));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use forces, if you want your rigidBody to move at constant speed.
Instead, set your ball's rigidBody `drag` to 0 and give it a starting velocity.

```
void Start(){
    rigi.velocity=new Vector3(1f,1f,0f); //set any starting velocity you want
}
```

Then you can just flip the direction of the movement, when the ball hits a wall:

```
OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) { 

   if(other.gameObject.tag == "rightWall" || other.gameObject.tag == "leftWall")
   {
       rigi.velocity=new Vector3(-rigi.velocity.x, rigi.velocity.y, rigi.velocity.z);

   } else if(other.gameObject.tag == "groundWall")
   {
       rigi.velocity = new Vector3(rigi.velocity.x, 10, rigi.velocity.z);
   }
}
```

In your case I would also advice making the rigidBody `kinematic` to avoid bugs with the movement

Comment: Well its not a pong game its pang both are different. But there is a one problem ball loose its high its behave like it have mass. Ball lost height every bounce.
tell me one more this is that -rigi.velocity.x is reversing velocity? I want to set fixed ball height.

Comment: -rigi.velocity.x is reverting the x-velocity. I edited my answer, so it behaves how i think you want it to. Now if the ball hits the "groundWall", it's y-Speed is set to 10, or whatever you want it to be

Comment: Thanks its working now. That the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly want to use an impulse rather than a force ( a force apply during a long time while an impulse is just more like a shock which stay 1 frame )
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html

Something like :

```
 rigid.AddForce(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3(300f, 0,0), Time.deltaTime * ballForce), ForceMode.Impulse);
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my go at it without using rigidbodies (more consistent bounce, esp. from device to device)

(Need a sphere collider on the bouncing ball to get it's radius, or can just hardcode the radius)

```
Vector3 gravity, velocity;
public float horzontalSpeed, gravitationalForce, groundVelocity;
float groundYPosition, wallAbsXPosition, radius;


private void Awake() {
    radius = GetComponent<Collider>().bounds.extents.y;
    
    groundYPosition = 0.0f;
    wallAbsXPosition = Camera.main.orthographicSize / 2;

    gravity = Vector3.down * gravitationalForce * Time.deltaTime;
    velocity.x = horzontalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}


private void Update() {
    if (transform.position.y <= groundYPosition + radius) {
        // set the ball's yPosition back to zero after hitting ground
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, radius, transform.position.z);
        // set the yVelocity after ground hit so you can control the height of the bounce
        velocity.y = groundVelocity;
    } else
        velocity += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x) >= wallAbsXPosition - radius)
        velocity.x *= -1;

    transform.Translate(velocity);
}
```